Finding Last Metric By Instance in 10day Period
I have a metric system_name and I want to return the last metric over the past 10 days by instance.
That is pretty simple but what I am confused about is we are scraping data from a device to get its system_name. If the devices system_name is changed over the 10 day period I will get a many to many matching if I try to group_left this metric with other metrics. I also can't group by instance because then the system_name will be lost.
So what I am trying to figure out is how to get the most recent value over the past 10 days. I have to use something like last_over_time because say the device goes offline, I still need to get its data so I can't look at the instant data which obviously would give me the most recent system_name value.
Currently I am doing this but this returns both metrics, the metric with the name before the name change and the metric after the name change by instance.
group(last_over_time(system_name{}[10d])) by (system_name, instance)
I understand this sounds like a relational database solution as opposed to time series, but I currently am seeing if my issue is possible to address with promql.

Try topk(1,last_over_time(timestamp(system_name) [10d:])) by (instance)

@markalex That worked thank you. I just had to alter the time range to [10d:6h] to improve the query speed. I understand by doing this it is not completely correct but its as close as I can get.
